# How iOS will inform the APNS server/ backend server when user uninstall application from iPhone?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have one app which is push notification enabled. How iOS can inform APNS server/backend server when user uninstall the application from iPhone? Something I found on this link on point number 3. http://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/FeedbackService

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to periodically query the APNS Feedback Service, which will provide you a list of inactive devices identified by their device tokens. Using this information, you'll be able to keep your backend server up to date.